Why not do range based hashing in server side in consistent hashing?
In consistent hashing, the reason we need vnodes is because we want to decrease variance via replication. Say you have a big hash ring, you hash 10 server ids to a hash ring, it's likely that each server gets uneven distribution of hash ranges.
What I don't understand is, why not do range based hashing on the server side then? Don't hash server id, just divvy up the hash range into 10 uniform pies, make each server be responsible for a pie. You get uniform distribution for free. Am I missing something?
I can't find any answer related to this. I've done my reading from
https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs168/l/l1.pdf
Consistent hashing, why are Vnodes a thing?
